# creating <tr> tag inside a for loop

Tags: php, css

I am creating a calendar.  So, I found some stuff online and now I am trying to make it work the way I need it.  The problem is that the days are created in a horizontal way.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

So, how you can see only `<td>` tag have been created.

I was trying to add `<tr>` tags for each 6 days so the calendar would look like a real calendar.

For example, day `7` should be under Monday, and day `8` on Tuesdays and so on.

I need help please.  Thanks.

PS: if you think the question is not clear enough please let me know before downvote this question.  I really would like to know what is going on.

Here is the code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

 class Calendar {  

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct(){     
    $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

/********************* PROPERTY ********************/  
private $dayLabels = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");

private $currentYear=0;

private $currentMonth=0;

private $currentDay=0;

private $currentDate=null;

private $daysInMonth=0;

private $naviHref= null;

/********************* PUBLIC **********************/  

/**
* print out the calendar
*/
public function show() {
    $year  = null;

    $month = null;

    if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

        $year = $_GET['year'];

    }else if(null==$year){

        $year = date("Y",time());  

    }          

    if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

        $month = $_GET['month'];

    }else if(null==$month){

        $month = date("m",time());

    }                  

    $this->currentYear=$year;

    $this->currentMonth=$month;

    $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

    $content='<fieldset>'. 
             '<legend class="cyan bold">Tutors Schedule</legend>'.

                    //head nav '<' & '>' buttons & month 
                    $this->_createNavi().
                    //end head


                    '<table class="table table-bordered">'.

                        '<thead>'.
                             '<tr>'.$this->_createLabels().'</tr>' .
                        '</thead>' .

                        '<tbody>'.
                          '<tr>';


                            $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                            // Create weeks in a month

                            for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){
                                 //create <tr> tags 

                                    //Create days in a week
                                    for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){

                                       $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);

                                    }  
                                    //Close </tr>
                            }



                         '</tbody>'.
                    '</table>';

   '</fieldset>';
    return $content;   
}

/********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
/**
* create the li element for ul
*/
private function _showDay($cellNumber){

    if($this->currentDay==0){

        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

        if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

            $this->currentDay=1;

        }
    }

    if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

        $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

        $this->currentDay++;   

    }else{

        $this->currentDate =null;

        $cellContent=null;
    }


    return '<td id="td-'.$this->currentDate.'" class=" td-top-text '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'"><div class="inside">'.$cellContent.'</div></td>';
}
```

}

**CSS:**

```
 /*Event Calendar Month */

.td-top-text {
 vertical-align: top;
 text-align: right;
 }

.inside-date, .td-top-text {
    text-align: right;
}
.inside-event {
    text-align: left;

}



td.td-top-text {
    width:14.2857142857%; /* 100% divided by 7 */
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;

}

td.td-top-text:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:100%;
    position: absolute;

}

td.td-top-text .inside {
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

Comment: please limit your posting to code that applies to the question.

Comment: @Dagon Sure...I will try my best...Thanks

Comment: Why don't your surround the days in week loop with `<tr>` and `</tr>`?

Comment: @Dagon Done.  i believe that the issue is between those two methods

Comment: @blahfunk not sure what you are saying.  :/ do you mean to add `<tr>` here `return '<td id="td-'.$this->currentDate.'" class=" td-top-text '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'"><div class="inside">'.$cellContent.'</div></td>';`

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Hi there, I already have an answer.  However, I would love to see your answer... Please provide a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand the question, but do you 
mean something like this?

```
                  for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){
                             $content .= "<tr>";

                                //Create days in a week
                                for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){

                                   $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);

                                }  
                                $content .= "</tr>";
                        }
```

Comment: Damn! yes... I was doing it wrong I was doing it this way `$content = "<tr>"` so you just added the `.` before `=`..can you explain a lil more please? but yess this is the answer.

Comment: ".=" in php is a concatenation.  same as $content = $content . "<tr>".  If you simply do an  "=" it will replace the previous content with the right side of the expression.

Comment: OoOOoOooOo!! wow i missed that! ....Thank you very much! I might be positing more question about this event calendar next week...I hope you still around and get those reputations =) .... Thanks!!!!!

Comment: If I am around and I see the questions I will do my best to answer.

Answer (score 1):

CSS example:

php code:

```
    $i = 1;
$content='<fieldset><legend class="cyan bold">Tutors Schedule</legend>';



foreach($dayName as $dd) {
    $content .= '<div>'.$dd.'</div>';
}
while($i <= $this->daysInMonth) {
    $content .= '<div>'.$i.'</div>';
}   

$content .= '</fieldset>';
```

```css
div:nth-child(7n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
</div>
```

Alot is possible this way: easy start on other days than monday '$i = -2; (example)';

This is just a basic little example don't copy and paste ;-)

Comment: Plus there are others ways to do this

Comment: Thank u i will double check this answer...;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `$count` variable that once it hits 7, it closes the row and opens a new row and resets the `$count` to 0. Increment the `$count` by 1 within the loop, and have the `if` statement checking if it has hit 7 also within that loop.